# Android custom Listview is too slow when using multiple Imageview in a ListItem

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I think the question is clear in title. I don't know how can I explain that but for ListView performance I tried so many thing such as using ViewHolder, keeping Bitmaps in a list and reference them in my adapter's getView() method, deleting every controlling and onClicklistener methods in getView() etc. But according to my experience, using 2 ImageView in one ListItem is OK but when using 3 ImageView both initializing and scrolling is extremly slow.

```
ArrayList<User> users;
Context context;
DatabaseHelper db;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Bitmap defaultImage;
ArrayList<Bitmap> userPhotos;
Bitmap messageImage;
Bitmap callImage;

public FriendsAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    users = db.getFriends();
    defaultImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.no_image_small);
    userPhotos = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
        if(users.get(i).getPhoto() != null && !users.get(i).getPhoto().isEmpty()){
            userPhotos.add(getCircularCroppedBitmap(stringToBitMap(users.get(i).getPhoto())));
        }
        else{
            userPhotos.add(null);
        }
    }
    messageImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.message);
    callImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.call);

}
```

Here you can see two image coming from drawable and one coming from string but it isn't important for siliding because all of them stored in variables.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_item_photo);
        holder.textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_item_name);
        holder.imageViewMessage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_item_message_photo);
        holder.imageViewCall = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_item_call_photo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.imageViewMessage.setImageBitmap(messageImage);
    //holder.imageViewCall.setImageBitmap(callImage);

    User user = users.get(position);

    Bitmap photo = userPhotos.get(position);
    if(photo == null){
        holder.imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(defaultImage);
    }
    else{
        holder.imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }

    holder.textViewName.setText(user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());


    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageViewPhoto;
    TextView textViewName;
    ImageView imageViewMessage;
    ImageView imageViewCall;

}
```

In this code everything is OK. But when I execute holder.imageViewCall.setImageBitmap(callImage); everything is too slow.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/friend_item_photo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/friend_item_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/friend_item_call_photo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/friend_item_message_photo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

It is my listItem xml. A linearLayout enclose that but I can't add it here. It is my first post.

Edit: It is already a base adapter.

Comment: Are the picture big? Maybe, you should use only a small version (thumbnail) of the picture in a list view... Maybe, you can test with very small picture to check if performance is improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guilherme P
"Are the picture big? Maybe, you should use only a small version (thumbnail) of the picture in a list view... Maybe, you can test with very small picture to check if performance is improved"

This is real answer. I forgot resizing images. Images coming from strings are small(125x125) but other two images are too big. One of them is 512x512, the other one is 1024x1024. I resized them to 100x100 and everything is smooth now. This is so basic and it should be first approach to find problem but there are so many things in project and many times basic ideas are overlooked.

Edit: Thanks for other answers but I done that things in so many activity and fragments. I know I do so many things in constructor but I have to do them. There are much more complex codes in other parts of project but there is no problems there.

Edit 2: Karakuri thanks you too. Your answer is good but my problem wasn't too complex. My code was work slow when only have 6-7 items. Your answer is true for hundreds of items. I will do that things later.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of your adapter is doing a **lot** of work on the main thread.

1. First you are doing a database query, which may be slow, or might block if another thread is writing to the database at the same time.
2. Your database code isn't posted, but it looks like you are iterating over the `Cursor` and building an `ArrayList` from the results. This is fine to do, but it takes time. If you were using the Cursor directly, you could return that right away once the query finished.
3. You iterate over all the results again and create an image for each item, which involves loading a bitmap from somewhere (I/O) and cropping it to a circle. Bitmap operations are usually not cheap. Also, you are creating these images for every item and storing that in memory, but the user may never see more than a small number of items. If you have a thousand items total and only 10 rows fit on screen, you are making 990 more images than you need right now. The user might never scroll through all the items, which means you wasted a lot of work for images that won't be seen.

Again, **all** of that is happening on the main thread. I would guess #3 is where most of the time is spent.

For issues 1 and 2, you should learn how to use the `Loader` framework or some other asynchronous mechanism to load your data on a background thread. Typically the Activity or Fragment is responsible for this, not the adapter itself. It may still take time, but it will be in the background, so the main thread is not blocked and you can show a loading spinner on screen while waiting.

For issue 3, you should use an image caching framework like Glide or Fresco. These libraries load images in the background on demand and cache them (so that if you need the same image again, it can skip the loading if the image is still cached). When `getView()` is called, start loading the image for that item. When the loading is done, set the image for that row -- usually these frameworks do that automatically, and you can even specify a default image to show while it's loading.

Answer (score 1):

Use image caching and loading library such as Glide, Picasso, etc.

Using an Async Task for loading images will also boost the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Recycler Views where built for this reason. Since you may be doing too much for your list views, it may be trying to do too much and thats what may be a cause to your issue. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: This is not an answer. You can't assume a RecyclerView will be faster without understanding why the ListView implementation is slow.